# Display Usernames in an ssh network?

Tags: ssh, terminal

I'm trying to ssh into a network.  When I get there, it prompts me for the password to the username I had entered with it.  However, I don't remember my username.

Is there any way perhaps to look at all the usernames listed within a network like this?  If I can do that, I can figure out which one is mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh by default will use the username of the account you're running it from. E.g. If you're logged into machine A as user 'xyz', then by default it'll transmit "username = xyz" to machine B when you try to ssh to it.

if you want to force a particular username, then use

```
ssh remoteusername@remotehost.com
```

If you've completely forgotten your remote username, then no... ssh will not scan the remote system and tell you what accounts are on it. That'd be a hideously BAD security hole.

Comment: The way I've been trying out different usernames is continuously trying `ssh an_attempted_username@remotehost.com`, then trying the known password I made for the the account.  I even tried other passwords to make sure it wasn't a password issue.  Well, I'll have to ask the administrator about this one.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's the best idea. Should've done that before you tried sshing. Repeated failed login attempts via ssh is a major hint that you're a bot trying to breakin. My own servers block repeated attempts at the firewall level

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely sure what you have and what you don't. If you know the password and are logged in, you can run the command `whoami` to know your username.